# Adding touch capabilities to rotation

Tags: javascript, touch, webgl

I am trying to add compatability for touch devices in the rotation of the 3d plot which uses [webgl-surface-plot](http://code.google.com/p/webgl-surface-plot/), but I cant get the most basic test to work. [here](http://bbhakhrani.bol.ucla.edu/SOCR_HTML5_BivariateNormalCalculator.html) is a link to the page. I have, for testing purposes added the following code, but I cant get this simple thing to work.

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
function tStart(e){document.getElementById("rangeSigmaX").innerHTML='touchstart';}
```

followed later by the following in the SurfacePlot.initGL function (SurfacePlot.js).

```
if(is_touch_device){
        var el = $('canvas.surfacePlotCanvas');
        el.addEventListener('touchstart', tStart, false);
        el.addEventListener("touchend", tStart, false);
        el.addEventListener("touchcancel", tStart, false);
        el.addEventListener("touchleave", tStart, false);
        el.addEventListener("touchmove", tStart, false); 
        }
```

None of these listeners seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.